# Textmate 2: How do I set the tab size for .rb files?

Tags: textmate2

I have a .tm_properties file in my home folder with the following contents:

```
softWrap = true
tabSize = 4
softTabs = true
```

However, if I open an .rb file and hit tab, it will only indent 2 spaces on the new line. How can I make it 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 seconds after I post the question I discover that this is managed in the View menu.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to global settings in the home folders `~/.tm_properties`, there are also `./.tm_properties` for file types (below) or by project (`[project folder]/.tm_properties`)

[Find more about the settings (credit dvessel)](https://gist.github.com/dvessel/1478685).

In short:

```
[ *.rb ]
  tabSize = 2
```